# I want to make a font switch between letter orientations for using it in office

Tags: css, fonts, custom-font

I created a font in Calligraphr and made a variant for each character which is the same character but upside down. I want to know if there’s a way to code or configure the font so every letter switches between the two types.

For example, let’s say I want to write SUGAR, the S would be just the same, but then the U would be upside down, then the G would be right side up and so on, switching for each letter...

But I don’t want a program that inverts them, I want to be able to use the font at any time in word or PowerPoint and make it flip every other letter automatically.

Comment: Could you describe/show what you have tried so far - have you investigated Office add-ins to see whether such a thing might be possible. In a webpage you'd be changing the HTML content to wrap each character in a span for example - can you alter the content in that sort of way in an Office add-in?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OpenType supports advanced typographic effects. One of the general capabilities is the ability to substitute default glyphs for alternate glyphs. Such glyph actions are triggered by "features". For example, small caps is a feature, and by enabling that font feature it can trigger actions to substitute default glyphs for letters to true small cap glyphs. (Simply scaling down glyphs does not produce typographically correct small caps.)

One of the OpenType features that would be suitable for what you want is [stylistic sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_pt#ssxx)—or, rather, there are 20 stylistic set features: SS 1, SS 2, etc. If a font supports stylistic set features, Word has UI that allows you to activate the feature.

[image]

Unfortunately, PowerPoint doesn't yet support OpenType features.

To implement this in your font, you need to create the alternate glyphs, define the substitution actions (OpenType defines these in "lookup" tables), and then associate the actions with the typographic features that will be used to activate them. Calligraphr probably doesn't support doing any of that. You'll need to use more capable font development tools. For GUI tools, [FontForge] is a free open source option, and [High-Logic FontCreator](http://www.fontcreator.com/) is another good, inexpensive option. Other more expensive options include [FontLab](https://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab/) and [Glyphs](https://glyphsapp.com/) (Mac only).